# Have stencil compiler ignore certain files?

Tags: stenciljs, stencil-compiler

A plugin is generating `*.json` files during the build and when I'm using the watch flag, it keep re-triggering the build forever.

Is there a way to tell Stencil to ignore certain filetypes on watch?

Comment: This is a bug that has been fixed in version 2.0.3.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading to 2.0.3, I was able to add the following to the stencil config and it worked: `watchIgnoredRegex: /\.*\.json$/`